# PHP encoding problem when copied to linux

Tags: php, encoding

I'm editing a php file in Notepad++ in a german language under Windows 7 x64 Ulti.
I'm encoding it with **Encode in UFT-8 without BOM.**
On my WAMP server locally everything is displayed correctly.
If I copy the file to a linux machine, and view the source, I see replaced characters like `ö, ä, ü` with some nonsense.

I also got this meta tag in header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

If I check it with W3C validator, this error appears:
*"The character encoding specified in the HTTP header (iso-8859-1) is different from the value in the  element (utf-8). I will use the value from the HTTP header (iso-8859-1) for this validation*"

It is a free hosting on: funpic.org

Why is that please?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue a `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` before displaying the HTML.

Comment: But could you explain me please, why do I have to do this in each file? I never had problems with this before..

Comment: It's possible that Apache httpd.conf or .htaccess on the server is set to a default character set of ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8. So issuing the above header overrides that setting.